# a kind of question where there is more than one option is correct

Tags: vocabulary

When I search "multiple choice questions", I get something like this

[image]

where there is actually only one option is correct.

What words could be referred to another type of question where there is more than one option is correct?

Comment: If the person misses being there, that means they no longer live there, so the perfect infinitive is the only choice.

Comment: Still you would have multiple choices though there is only one option is correct (or there are more). So, I would say all of them are MCQuestions.

Comment: @Cardinal Thank you. MC stands for "multiple choice", right?

Comment: Yes, I meant multiple choices. sorry for the laziness :embarrassed_while_smiling:

Answer (score 2):

These are just a variant of "multiple choice question".  They are "multiple-choice questions with more than one correct answer"

There are actually (at least) 2 sub-variants:  Questions where candidates have to find *all* the correct solutions, and questions were candidates have to find any of the correct solutions.

Every system I've used for creating multiple choice quizzes has had an option for "more than one correct answer".  It is quite common to phrase a question as "Which two answers are correct?"

Comment: Thank you. How about this type of questions where one to four answers are correct? For example, question 1 just has one correct answer while all four are correct to question 2.